# Image must be placed in the same folder as component?

Tags: android, react-native

I have my image under

```
/app/assets/images/logo/logo.png
```

If I have a component under `/app/components/headerbar/headerbar.js` it can't use  `<Image source={require('./app/assets/images/logo/logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />`
because it says "module not found [..]"

However if I place my image under the same folder as the `headerbar.js` file and change path to `./logo.png` then it works fine. Setting the path to `../app/assets/images/logo/logo.png` doesn't work either.

Do I have to have the static image under the same folder as the component for it to work in RN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference the file like this: require('../../assets/images/logo/logo.png')

Alternatively put a js file in your app root and reference your assets in there, exporting them as consts:

```
export const LOGO = require('./assets/images/logo/logo.png');
```

Then you can simply import the const and write

```
<Image source={LOGO} style={styles.logo} />
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved by changing path to:  <Image source={require('../../../app/assets/images/logo/logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />